# ndepend; get method's arguments

Tags: ndepend

How can I, using CQLINQ, get collection of input arguments for current method? There is any collection like "Arguments" or "Parameters" only "NbParamenter" which is not suitable for my purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, CQLinq doesn't have this feature yet. However, in many cases you can compensate thanks to the fact that the properties [ICodeElement.Name](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.CodeModel.ICodeElement~Name.html) and [IMember.FullName](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.CodeModel.IMember~FullName.html), for a [IMethod](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.CodeModel.IMethod_members.html), contain the coma separated list of names of the parameters types. For example here is the `FullName` of a method:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Control.BeginInvoke(Delegate,Object[])
```

and here is its `Name`:

```
BeginInvoke(Delegate,Object[])
```

Here is for example a CQLinq rule that harnesses parameters types names, to match event handlers methods:

```
// <Name>Event handler methods should be declared private</Name>
warnif count > 0
from m in Application.Methods where 
  !m.IsPrivate &&

   // A method is considered as event handler if...
   m.NbParameters == 2 &&            // ...it has two parameters..
   m.Name.Contains("Object") &&    // ...of types Object...
   m.Name.Contains("EventArgs") && // ...and EventArgs

   // Discard special cases
  !m.ParentType.IsDelegate &&
  !m.IsGeneratedByCompiler

select new { m,m.Visibility }
// This rule implementation relies on the facts that:
// -> A method name contains the type of its parameters.
// -> All EventArgs derived types have the suffix "EventArgs".
```

Comment: This is fine if you only want the type, but doesn't help if you want to look for specific parameter names :(

Comment: Has nDepend 6 resolved this?  I wanted to get a list of parameters and their _attributes_ if any.  e.g. `[CallerMemberName]`.  As tjrobinson mentions, the above code does not seem to help in our case.

Comment: Still no such feature in NDepend 6.2.1 with CQLinq 1.9. Pity.

Comment: From what I can tell the method name solution doesn't let you look for optional arguments that have been added to methods either.  This is unfortunate, as optional arguments can introduce breaking changes to your API and a way to warn against them would be nice.  Is there something additional to do?

Comment: No we don't have more method argument support but this will definitely be part of future features

Comment: I need to check where do parameters come from in order to ensure, that the business logic doesn't get polluted with types from another module. So it is allowed to call another module's API and consume its data, but it has to be transformed into local data structures.

I'd ideally check if the parameter namespace in a method is from my namespace. Is that possible? This should match the above mentioned feature.

Comment: not yet unfortunately, but you can at least check if the parent type of your method(s) is using only certain other types